# Como alterar o local onde o MAMP cria o banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, mamp

Gostaria de mudar o local aonde o [mamp](/questions/tagged/mamp) cria o banco de dados.

O padrão seria este:

> /Applications/MAMP/db/

E gostaria de criar por padrão o Banco de dados no meu servidor que seria:

> /Volumes/Sites/

Alguém sabe algum método que sirva para mudar essa configuração padrão dele?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer isso, instalei o WAMP no meu servidor e peguei o número de IP dele.

E agora na meu Browser é só deixar o endereço como abaixo:

> (IP do meu servidor)/localhost/WAMP/

E então consigo acessar a página inicial e quando crio um Banco de Dados, ele deixa no meu servidor.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o mais prático seja você criar um link simbólico em `/Applications/MAMP/db` apontando para `/Volumes/Sites`.

Se a pasta `db` já tiver sido criada, mova-a primeiro para o destino:

```sh
mv /Applications/MAMP/db /Volumes/Sites
```

(assumindo que a pasta `Sites` ainda não existe)

Então crie o link simbólico:

```sh
ln -s /Volumes/Sites /Applications/MAMP/db
```

Comment: Então @rodrigorgs no caso essa pasta que me refiro está em um servidor fora do meu computador de trabalho.